# In the C language, how to use static function of non-current file?

Tags: c, static, static-functions

fileA.c has a static function (static int funcA())

The fileA.c can not be modified.

fileB.c How can I use the funcA()?

Comment: What's the purpose? the `static` is added for a reason, no?

Comment: The product code has a static function. And now, we're doing the unit testing, we can only write test case code to test it, but can't change the produce code.

Comment: `#include "fileA.c"`

Answer (score 1):

In general you cannot, that's the entire point of `static` in this case.

Perhaps `fileA.c` has a way to get the address of the function, then you can use that to make a call, but you can't reference `static` symbols directly.

For test code, one "trick" that's often done is to `#include` the C file in the test file, so in `fileA_test.c` you'd have:

```
#include "fileA.c"

bool test_fileA_something(void)
{
  TEST_ASSERT(foo() == 42);
}
```

The above assumes that `foo` is a `static` function inside `fileA.c`, and this works since the files are compiled together.

Answer (score 0):

Not. The compiler has every right to not include `funcA` in fileA.obj. And even if it is included, it might not be in a form that the linker can use. In fact, if included it must be in a way that doesn't clash with other functions names `funcA`